# How to Set the URL property of a Web Browser control to a String

Tags: webbrowser-control, uri

I'm using a Web Browser control in C# and I'd like to be able to plug in different URLs depending on other things that have happened in the program. How can I set the URL property to a string in the code? Can I convert a string to the System.Uri type?

```
string link;
string searchedtitle = "The+Italian+Job";
link = "http://www.imdb.com/find?s=all&q=" + searchedtitle + "&x=0y=0";
WbBrowser.Url = link; // This is what I don't know how to do
```

Something to that effect would be ideal, where I could change 'searchedtitle' within the program somewhere else and still have it run properly. Unfortunately, the *Url* property is of type `System.Uri`, and I only have a `System.String`.

Comment: Did you ever find the documentation of the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url.aspx) property?

Answer (score 11):

WbBrowser.Url is of type [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) so you need to use

```
WbBrowser.Url = new Uri(link);
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that setting the URL is exactly the same as calling the Navigate() function. Navigate takes a string as an argument as the URL, eliminating the step of converting your URL to a string.

Comment: I suppose that should have been apparent. Thank you for your help, problem solved.